# Connection Problems with multiple access points with single SSID

Tags: wireless-router, connection, wireless-access-point

I have an android tablet from insignia running jelly bean. The campus center at my school has multiple routers in it with the same `ssid`. However when I attempt to connect to the internet the connection jumps around to all the routers and never establishes a solid connection. Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: oh damnit, just re-read your post, and realised you're talking about Android.  No clue on that front I'm afraid!

I just discovered a partial solution to this.

The utility WirelessMon (http://www.passmark.com/products/wirelessmonitor.htm) allows you to override Windows wifi selection, and explicitly connect to an AP by MAC address instead of SSID.  It's quite useful for checking general wifi quality too.

The downsides of using WirelessMon are, it's only a 30-day trial, and it also tends to screw up the connection itself by constantly scanning in the background. The best solution I've found is to set its sampling rate to the maximum of 60 seconds, which helps enormously compared to the default of 3.

I'd really like to find a free app that does the same thing.  Even better if all it does is the MAC thing, and no background scanning.